# If $A$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R}$, is it diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been wondering, if a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable  in $\mathbb{R}$, is it diagonalizable  in $\mathbb{C}$? It seems like an obvious yes, but I'm scared I'm missing something. Is my fear grounded or is it really just that obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an obvious yes. If $B$ is a real matrix such that $BAB^{-1}$ is diagonal, then $B$ is also a complex matirx and $BAB^{-1}$ is still diagonal

Comment: Ok thanks, so I didn't miss something. I thought perhaps it's possible in $\mathbb{C}$ there could be additional eigenvalues with ruined everything.